# integrating payment with credit card in a win32 software

Tags: c#, api, payment

I have a software written in c# that delivered to two client that receive orders. The two company asked me to integrate a solution for paying with credit card.

I am a little bit confused from what I had googled. I think that paypal professional solution is the one that fits the best but I need that the two company register themselves in UK or US or otherwise I cannot use direct payment solutions with the integrated c# paypal api.

I was thinking to save the credit card information in a PCI compliant hosting service so I have the possibility to let the customers save they credit card for recurrent payment.

But in this case which payment gateway should I use that integrate c# api for direct payment with credit card?

really I do not know what is the best and legal solution I would avoid putting a month in coding and find finally that the solution is not compliant with the credit card circuit

Any comments/help will be appreciate.

Paolo

Answer (score 2):

There are many third party payment gateway available online, Litle payment gateway I think will solve your problem, here is the developer guide http://www.litle.com/developers/processing-overview/

Answer (score 0):

The best advice when it comes to *storing* credit card information is this: **dont**. Yes, there are ways to do it, but it only increases your liability. Maybe the product you're working on has a compelling reason to do it; I don't know, but you would do well to work with a certified PCI auditing firm to get more specific guidance on that.

As for which payment gateway to use, questions looking for product recommendations are generally discouraged on SO (ideally an answer on SO doesn't have a shelf life, or at least not a short one). There are plenty of them out there (Authorize.net, Merchant Warehouse, PayPal, etc.) that all have their own web-services-based API, so find the one that works best for your customer(s) and use that.